# OpenGL ES GLSL optimization

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl

I'm developing a game which uses glsl shader to produce terrain based on the vertex "height". This works very very fast on desktop but quite slow on android tablet. This is of course natural. I'm still a noob with GLSL and OpenGL. This is the result from the shader:

[image]

lowp setting doesn't affect that much for performance. I have now tuned this and frame rate is ~20. Can someone give ideas how to improve this shader code:

Fragment shader:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
#define LOWP lowp
precision mediump float;
#else
#define LOWP
#endif

varying float EyeVertexZ;
//varying LOWP float Explored;
varying LOWP vec2 v_texCoords;
uniform LOWP float u_offset;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform sampler2D u_texture2;
uniform sampler2D u_texture3;
uniform vec2 resolution;



void main() {



         LOWP vec4 color;
         vec4 colorGrass = vec4(0.631, 0.69, 0.49 ,1.0);
           float a;
            float height = EyeVertexZ;

         color = colorGrass;
         //if height under 0.67 --> water
         if(height < 0.67)
         {
            vec2 coords = v_texCoords.st;
            coords.x -= u_offset;
                LOWP vec3 nColor;
                float bumpAmount = 0.2;

                //bumpmapping texture
            nColor = texture2D(u_texture,  coords).rgb;

            //water color, deep water darker
            color = vec4(0.3, 0.4 + EyeVertexZ*0.33,0.6 + EyeVertexZ*0.33 ,1.0);

            bool useNormals = true;
            bool useShadow = true;
            bool yInvert = false;
            vec3 lightColor = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
            vec3 attenuation = vec3(0.5, 0.5,0.5);
            vec3 ambientColor = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
            vec4 v_color = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
            float ambientIntensity = 0.3;
            vec3 light = vec3(resolution.x, 0.0, 0.5);

            //some bump map programs will need the Y value flipped..
            nColor.g = yInvert ? 1.0 - nColor.g : nColor.g;

            //this is for debugging purposes, allowing us to lower the intensity of our bump map
            LOWP vec3 nBase = vec3(0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
            nColor = mix(nBase, nColor, bumpAmount);

            //normals need to be converted to [-1.0, 1.0] range and normalized
            LOWP vec3 normal = normalize(nColor * 2.0 - 1.0);



            //here we do a simple distance calculation
            LOWP vec3 deltaPos = vec3( (light.xy - gl_FragCoord.xy) / resolution.xy, light.z);

            LOWP vec3 lightDir = normalize(deltaPos);
            LOWP float lambert = useNormals ? clamp(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0, 1.0) : 1.0;

            //now let's get a nice little falloff
            LOWP float d = sqrt(dot(deltaPos, deltaPos));
            LOWP float att = useShadow ? 1.0 / ( attenuation.x + (attenuation.y*d) + (attenuation.z*d*d) ) : 1.0;

            LOWP vec3 result = (ambientColor * ambientIntensity) + (lightColor.rgb * lambert) * att;
            result *= color.rgb;

            color = v_color * vec4(result, color.a);
         }

         a = height - 0.65;
         a = max(a,0.0);
            color = mix(color, texture2D(u_texture2, v_texCoords),a < 0.02 ? a*50.0 : 0.0);

         if(height > 0.67 && height <= 0.70)
         {
            a = height-0.67;
            color = mix( texture2D(u_texture2, v_texCoords),color, a*33.0);
         }

         gl_FragColor = color; //mix(color, hex, hex.a);

}
```

Vertex shader

```
#ifdef GL_ES
#define LOWP lowp
precision mediump float;
#else
#define LOWP
#endif

attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoords;
uniform mat4 u_worldView;
varying LOWP float noise;

varying float EyeVertexZ;
varying LOWP float Explored;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;

void main() {

   gl_Position = u_worldView*a_position;
    EyeVertexZ = a_position.z;
   v_texCoords = a_texCoords;
}
```

Comment: At first glance I don't see anything too strange or obvious performance killers. Maybe your expectations regarding your Android tablet are too high. Which exact tablet are you using?

Comment: The "if" looks suspicious. It "might" be faster to just calculate all values and then multiply them by the clamped max of your threshholds. Also by looking at the image this looks very static, so why not calculated it once and just use a texture?

Comment: Danny R: thanks for the comment. It could be true that my expectations are too high. The tablet it Asus Transformer TF700T.

Andreas: I noticed that branching is one performance killer and I have reduced it. The image will not be static, it is a strategy game and my picture is when zoom out is at max. I would like to get natural looking water with bumpmapping and some movement  which I'm doing with coords.x -= u_offset;

Comment: Looks like that's based on Nvidia Tegra3, same as the Nexus 7 (2012).  I saw sluggish performance on the N7 when using shaders to process camera frames.  (Try "show + capture camera" in Grafika, https://github.com/google/grafika, and see if you get a massive performance dip when you turn the filtering on.)  I believe part of the issueis that the Tegra3 shaders don't support branching, so essentially all of the code gets executed every time.  Do you have a qcom Adreno device you can test on?